# FQL like table and applications

Tags: facebook

Is query from [like table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like) requires any permission? 
Could this query used for application?

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="appID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "like" FQL table returns the IDs of users who like a given object (video, note, link, photo, or album). It will not work for an app. You like the app's page.

This is similar to:

[How do i find out if a user has liked my facebook app? (not a fan page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132427/how-do-i-find-out-if-a-user-has-liked-my-facebook-app-not-a-fan-page)