# How do i find out if a user has liked my facebook app? (not a fan page)

Tags: php, facebook

i can find out if user liked my facebook fan page ...

but now i have a facebook app (which i think doesn't have a page_id) and can't figure out how to do so. i've scoured the web but only resources i see are related to facebook page.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know there is no possibility to do that. a user can't like your app, only the page it sits in.